# Magento doesn't switch to right locale while installing

Tags: language, locale

I'm trying to deploy a dutch install of magento 1.9.2.3, but i can't seem to get the locale set to dutch.

As far as i can remember, i used to selected 'Nederlands' while installing and then everything in back and frontend would be dutch. Now i do the same but my entire install remains english.

What am i missing? I've tried to remove the files and run the install again like ten times but its not working.

The person that can tell me what i'm doing wrong gets a cookie!

Comment: I'm in for the cookie. Did you try installing with full permissions (777) on your Magento folder just to see if it's still happening ?

Comment: Nope.. did a chmod -R 777 on the root folder but no result.. thanks for the reply anyways, it could have been the solution.

Comment: Does it happen only with dutch locale or for every other locale ?

Comment: every locale, the title 'Localization' and other text is supposed to change when the locale is changed and the page reloads right?

Comment: Yes it should change

Comment: Did you use another Magento version before? Cause I think it doesn't contain NL language files by default. So you have to install a locale package first